# Dialogflow multi-language integration

Tags: integration, multilingual, dialogflow-es

I have a working agent in two languages. But when I use Integrations option with Twitter and Facebook only default language is available.

How can I setup Dialogflow to have both languages working on Twitter and Facebook?

Note: Integration with Google Assitant works in both

Thanks!

Comment: I have the same problem with Facebook Messenger. I tried changing my Facebook default language to test another language, but that doesn't help. DialogFlow only replies in its default language.

Answer (score 2):

There's no way you can do that according to documentation. Dialogflow integration works only in its default language. [Last paragraph of the page](https://cloud.google.com/dialogflow/docs/agents-multilingual)

Answer (score -2):

Dialogflow has multi-language support for 16 languages, so so I’m going to show you how to build a multi-language Chatfuel bot with one of Dialogflow’s built-in languages. We’ll also use the Multi-language Dialogflow template from Chatfuel. You can browse Chatfuel’s templates and just add that to your Dashboard. If your language is not supported by Dialogflow, you can still use Dialogflow with an unsupported language, just skip ahead in this document to Building a multi-language Chatfuel bot with an unsupported Dialogflow language.
Please refer below URL further clarification
https://medium.com/janis/how-to-build-a-smart-multilingual-chatfuel-bot-with-a-single-dialogflow-ai-agent-49f9c0eab395